# Add-on to block websites on Ubuntu Web Browser (Epiphany)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, website-blocker, epiphany

I need an extension or add-on for the Ubuntu web browser (the browser which is provided by Ubuntu other than Firefox) to block some websites in my Ubuntu 14.04.

I need an add-on like the 'Leech Block' add-on for Firefox. The greatest advantage of that add-on is that we can block websites on scheduled time intervals. This is the most important feature I want.

So can anyone suggest an add-on of such type for Ubuntu Web Browser?

Comment: "Firefox is the default web browser in Ubuntu." https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsers Please tell us what browser you use, it probably says its name in Help>About

Comment: For the record: the "Ubuntu Web Browser" most likely refers to [Epiphany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_(web_browser)). In Ubuntu's menus, it's just named "Webbrowser".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul This browser has no menu at all. If you have Ubuntu just search "browser" and you can see it.

Comment: Could you please type "about:" in the URL bar and tell us what happens? Does it have a preference dialog, for instance to change association settings? If not, could you please send a screenshot?